# FFmpeg on Android - Unable to find a suitable output format

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, format, native

I want to reduce the resolution of a video before edit it, so I´m using ffmpeg on android. I´m using the executable/binary file of ffmpeg and I´m calling my ffmpeg commands like that:

```
./ffmpeg -i /sdcard/dcim/video.mp4 -s 320x240 -r 10 -y /sdcard/output.mp4
```

But when I try this command I get this error:

> Unable to find a suitable output format for /sdcard/output.mp4

This is the output when I use the adb shell: [image]

The only action I have been able to do is to extract the audio of a video and save it as a mp3 using this command:

```
./ffmpeg -i /sdcard/dcim/video.mp4 -y /sdcard/output.mp3
```

That works well but this is the only action I can do...
Any idea of why I can´t convert a video? (I can´t copy it too) Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on my executable ffmpeg file... It didn´t work correctly. I tried with the ffmpeg file from [this project](https://github.com/JayH5/android-ffmpeg-cmdline) and it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try other command line. Try to change the frame rate, 10 maybe is not suitable and specify de encoder.

```
ffmpeg -i /sdcard/dcim/video.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -s 320x240 -r 25 -y /sdcard/output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried a lot of different combinations and any of them works if the output is a video... I don´t know what happens. Could it be that my binary file is badly compiled?? Do you have a correct one or do you know how to get it?? Thanks for help, really